# SQL Server Pivot Sum Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this type of data:
[ORIGINAL DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VcNK.jpg)

I want to generate report like this.
[NEED DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u46cg.jpg)

How it is possible for me using sql server.

Comment: Please show data and code as formatted text, not as (link to) image. Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes. I am trying Pivot, not not correct data.

Comment: @KETULSONI - Post the code which you tried so far

Comment: Is it always the same 4 options (design, coding, testing, database)?

Comment: NO column is dynamic. Thanks JohnHC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(Process)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT Process FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
  ) AS x;
SET @sql = N'SELECT [Date],' 
+ STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') 
+ 'FROM
(

SELECT [Date], Qty,Process FROM SAMPLE_TABLE

) AS j PIVOT
(
  SUM(Qty) FOR Process IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', [', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p ORDER BY p.[Date];';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with pivot if it's always these 4 options... Use a conditional aggregate

```
select Date, 
   sum(case when Process = 'DESIGN' then Qty else 0 end) as DESIGN,
   sum(case when Process = 'CODING' then Qty else 0 end) as CODING,
   sum(case when Process = 'TESTING' then Qty else 0 end) as TESTING,
   sum(case when Process = 'DATABASE' then Qty else 0 end) as [DATABASE]
from MyTable
group by Date
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the desired Result by using Dynamic sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOt NUll
Drop Table #Temp
;With cte (Developer,   Process ,Qty,   Date)
AS
(
SELECT 'XYZ','Design',  10      ,'26/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'XYZ','Codein',  20  ,'26/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'XYZ','Testin',  30  ,'26/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'XYZ','Databa',  40  ,'26/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'ABC','Design',  10      ,'26/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'ABC','Codein',  20  ,'26/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'ABC','Testin',  30  ,'26/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'ABC','Databa',  40  ,'27/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'XYZ','Design',  50      ,'27/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'XYZ','Codein',  60  ,'27/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'XYZ','Testin',  70  ,'27/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'XYZ','Databa',  80  ,'27/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'ABC','Design',  50      ,'27/06/2017' Union all     
SELECT 'ABC','Codein',  60  ,'27/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'ABC','Testin',  70  ,'27/06/2017' Union all
SELECT 'ABC','Databa',  80  ,'27/06/2017' 
)
SELECT * INTO  #Temp FROM cte

--Above i have created sample data for getting result

DECLARE @dynamicCol nvarchar(max),
        @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @dynamicCol2 nvarchar(max),
        @dynamicCol3 nvarchar(max)

SELECT @dynamicCol=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + 'ISNULL('+Process +',''0'')  AS '+ Process  FROM  #Temp
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @dynamicCol2=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Process  FROM  #Temp
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @dynamicCol3=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + 'SUM( '+Process +' ) OVER( Partition by [Date] )  AS '+ Process  FROM  #Temp
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')



SET @Sql='SELECT DISTINCT [Date],'+@dynamicCol3+' FROM
            (
            SELECT  [Date] , '+ @dynamicCol +' From
            (
            SELECT * From
            #temp
            )AS Src
            PIVOT 
            (
            MAX([Qty]) For [Process ] IN ('+@dynamicCol2+')
            )
            AS Pvt
            )DT
            '

PRINT @Sql

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want specific pivot and result view as mention but want data than use below

```
select Date1,cast(Process as varchar(200)) Status,sum(Qty) as Count from #temp group by Date1,Process
```